# I can't find the 'comment' button, why?

Tags: support

I can't find the 'comment' button when i want to comment on others' questions or answers. Why?

Comment: Maybe because this "add comment" looks more like a link than a button? Can you post some screenshot featuring the lack of that feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [50 reputation to comment on posts other than your own](https://physics.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment). That is the reason why you don't see the comment link.

Comment: ok,thanks a lot